# неопределенная ссылка

Tags: c++

Eсть такой код, думаю этого примера достаточно, потому что в нём ошибка, я не знаю что делать.

```
160 class Scene {
161         public:
162                 static Store *store;
163                 static void alloc_store ( int count ) {
164                         store = new Store ( count );
165                 }
166                 static void add ( Actor *actor, int pos ) {
167                         store->add ( actor, pos );
168                 }
169                 static void rm ( Actor *actor, int pos ) {
170                         store->rm ( actor, pos );
171                 }
172                 static void draw ( ) {
173                         store->draw ( 0 );
174                         store->draw ( 1 );
175                         store->draw ( 2 );
176                         store->draw ( 3 );
177                 }
178 };
```

При компиляции пишет вот что.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccLwGNMG.o: в функции «Scene::alloc_store(int)»:
/home/cf/projects/papsy/./src/menu/../engine/scene.h:164: неопределённая ссылка на «Scene::store»
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccLwGNMG.o: в функции «Scene::add(Actor*, int)»:
/home/cf/projects/papsy/./src/menu/../engine/scene.h:167: неопределённая ссылка на «Scene::store»
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccLwGNMG.o: в функции «Scene::draw()»:
/home/cf/projects/papsy/./src/menu/../engine/scene.h:173: неопределённая ссылка на «Scene::store»
/usr/bin/ld: /home/cf/projects/papsy/./src/menu/../engine/scene.h:174: неопределённая ссылка на «Scene::store»
/usr/bin/ld: /home/cf/projects/papsy/./src/menu/../engine/scene.h:175: неопределённая ссылка на «Scene::store»
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccLwGNMG.o:/home/cf/projects/papsy/./src/menu/../engine/scene.h:176: далее есть ещё неопределённые ссылки на «Scene::store»
```

Answer (score 1):

Допиши куда-нибудь определение поля:

```
Store *Scene::store = 0;
```

Comment: инквизиция уже выехала... они разъяснят священную разницу между *определением* и *объявлением*...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, вроде исправил. Я вообще хотел как дубликат закрыть, но не нашёл...

Comment: @Qwertiy, не до конца исправили _ инициализируйте  указатель(он не имеет дефолтное значение)

Comment: @Qwertiy а почему так надо делать?

Comment: @xverizex потому-что объявленных, но не определённых переменных как бы и не существует. Как ей пользоваться ? Компилятор поэтому и ругается

Comment: @xverizex, строгое объяснение — «потому что так требует язык»... рациональное зерно за этим состоит в том, чтобы дать компилятору знать в какой объектник пристроить символ...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, исправил. Глобальные переменные же сами обнуляются - я думал, что и тут так же?